# How to draw a voltmeter and ammeter using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw at voltmeter and ammeter with a pointer and a scale using tikz so that students can read off values?
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? More complicated than you need, but the following should give you plenty of ideas to work with: [Is there a triangular protractor shape built-in to TikZ?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/289026)

Comment: Also helpful: [Creating a audio volume dial using tikz](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/525535), [Draw Clock to help learn time](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/343622), [Generate analog clock with numbered face](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/132321), and [Generate analog clock with numbered face, add seconds, Roman numerals](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/236923)

Comment: Thanks for these examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (0,0) circle(8pt);
        \draw[line width=3pt] (39:6) arc (39:141:6);
        \foreach \an in {140,138,...,40}
            \draw[line width=2pt] (\an:6)--(\an:6.3);
        \foreach \an [count=\c] in {140,130,...,40}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{int(\c-1)}
            \draw[line width=3] (\an:6)--(\an:6.5) node[pos=1.7] () {\huge \bfseries \s};
        }
        \draw[-stealth,line width=4pt] (0,0)--(113:5.9);
        \node at (0,3) {\bfseries \huge V};
    \end{tikzpicture}\qquad
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (0,0) circle(8pt);
        \draw[line width=2pt] (29:6) arc (29:151:6);
        \foreach \an in {140,130,...,40}
            \draw[line width=2pt] (\an:5.8)--(\an:6);
        \foreach \an/\lab  in {140/0.0,120/0.2,100/0.4,80/0.6,60/0.8,40/1.0}{
            
            \draw[line width=3] (\an:6)--(\an:5.6) node[pos=1.9] () {\Large \bfseries \lab};
        }
        \draw[-stealth,line width=4pt] (0,0)--(113:5);
        \node at (0,3) {\bfseries \huge A};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**ADD**: I have modified the preceding code by defining two new commands: `\vt` and `\am`, each one with one numeric parameter. This parameter is the value of the measure so that the big arrow on each picture point to the value desired. If we write in the code `\vt{6.2}` the big arrow on the voltmeter point to the value 6.2 V.
Here is my code revisited code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\newcommand{\vt}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw[fill=cyan!30,draw=blue,line width=5pt] (-6.5,-1) rectangle (6.5,8);
\fill (0,0) circle(8pt);
\draw[line width=3pt] (39:6) arc (39:141:6);
\foreach \an in {140,138,...,40}
\draw[line width=2pt] (\an:6)--(\an:6.3);
\foreach \an [count=\c] in {140,130,...,40}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{int(\c-1)}
    \draw[line width=3] (\an:6)--(\an:6.5) node[pos=1.7] () {\huge \bfseries \s};
}
\draw[-stealth,line width=4pt] (0,0)--({140-10*#1}:5.9);
\node at (0,3) {\bfseries \huge V};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\am}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[fill=cyan!30,draw=blue,line width=5pt] (-6.5,-1) rectangle (6.5,8);
        \fill (0,0) circle(8pt);
        \draw[line width=2pt] (29:6) arc (29:151:6);
        \foreach \an in {140,130,...,40}
        \draw[line width=2pt] (\an:5.8)--(\an:6);
        \foreach \an/\lab  in {140/0.0,120/0.2,100/0.4,80/0.6,60/0.8,40/1.0}{
            
            \draw[line width=3] (\an:6)--(\an:5.6) node[pos=1.9] () {\Large \bfseries \lab};
        }
        \draw[-stealth,line width=4pt] (0,0)--({140-100*#1}:5);
        \node at (0,3) {\bfseries \huge A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1][1-5]\\
    \begin{center}
        \vt{6.2}
    \end{center}
    \lipsum[2][3-12]\\
    \begin{center}
        \am{.3}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for this code. It works exactly as I need. I was using something similar by drawing an arc. But this clears up some of my misunderstandings.

Comment: @akasteve After Your enthusiasm You can also accept my answer.

Comment: Accepted. Also, the modified code is excellent.